# Replace emojis with text

Tags: python, replace

Can somebody help me I'm a newbie at python. I tried to perform this task but get nowhere. The task is the following:

Your task is to write a program that accepts some text from the keyboard and replaces emojis with words according to the following principle:

```
X-( Angry

</3 Broken Heart

:_( Crying

:*) Drunk

|-O Yawn

;) Winking

;-) Winking

:S Sarcastic

:-( Sad

XD Laughing

:) Happy

:-) Happy

:-* Kiss

:-)* Kiss

:-P Frustrated
```

**Example**

**Input**:
I like you so much :( How it's going :-P :-P

**Output**:
I like you so much Sad How it's going Frustrated Frustrated

Comment: post what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that hopefully will get you started

```py
emojis = {
':_(': 'Crying'
':*)': 'Drunk'
}

s = "Hello I'm :_("
for emoji, replacement in emojis.items():
  s = s.replace(emoji, replacement)

print(s) # Hello I'm Crying
```